# c# reusable property to be called passed by lambda

Tags: c#, lambda, linq-expressions

I'm trying to write a method that would take an object with property name as a lambda parameter, and use it on passed object, but also use it on another, new object of the same type created inside that method.

The goal is to use the same property on both objects. The property name should be passed as a parameter to the method (lambda expression).

Let me show what I've written so far (doesn't compile):

Object to be used:

```
public class ObjectMy
{
  public string Prop1 {get; set;}
}
```

Method in another class to be used with above object:

```
public class TestClass1
{
    public void DoSomethingOnProperty(Expression<Func<ObjectMy,string>> propertyName)
    {
        var object1 = new ObjectMy();
        var propertyNameProp = propertyName.Body as MemberExpression;
        propertyNameProp.Member = "Test string"; // error Member is readonly

        //DoSomethingOnProperty(object1.thesameproperty...)

    }
}
```

I want to set passed in method's name property of ObjectMy's instance to "Test string"
and then recursively call DoSomethingOnProperty on another, new instance of ObjectMy, and use the same property name as given in the first call to DoSomethingOnProperty.

I'd like to call it like

```
DoSomethingOnProperty(obj=>obj.Prop1);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Backwards!!! .Select(x => DoSomethingOnPropery(x)).  The method should DoSomethingOnPropery should return a value, not use void.  If you just want to change the value then put code into a for loop.

Comment: So `DoSomethingOnProperty` should modify the same property in multiple objects? Then why does it only have a 'property name' argument but not an `ObjectMy` argument? You're trying to modify an expression, which is a representation of code. At that point there isn't even any `ObjectMy` instance to work with at all.

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly then a much easier solution would be to pass in a set-property method, so your method can call it on as many objects as it wants: `DoSomethingOnProperty(Action<ObjectMy, string> setProperty) { var object1 = new ObjectMy(); setProperty(object1, "Test string"); ... }`. This can then be called as following: `DoSomething((obj, value) => { obj.Prop1 = value; })`.

Comment: Your real objective is not clear to me. You currently have a small problem in manipulating Expression trees, but IMO it is quite possible the solution to your problem can ignore expression trees altogether. Do you need to set the value of the property? What is __inside__ DoSomethingWithProperty?

Comment: Thanks for your answers. @mitsbits solution is what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your method like this:

```
public void DoSomethingOnProperty<T>(Expression<Func<T, dynamic>> propertyName) where T : class, new()
    {
        var object1 = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
        var methodName = (propertyName.Body as MemberExpression).Member.Name;
        var propertyInfo = typeof(T).GetProperty(methodName);
        typeof(T).GetProperty(methodName).SetValue(object1, Convert.ChangeType("Test string", propertyInfo.PropertyType));

        //DoSomethingOnProperty(object1.thesameproperty...)

    }
```

you could use it like

```
DoSomethingOnProperty<ObjectMy>(x => x.Prop1);
```